# Open source web based java reporting tool

Tags: java, reporting

Is there an open source web based java reporting tool with admin feature to create reports?

Answer (score 7):

I've been really impressed with [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) and [JasperServer](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperserver), it works really well for me and the [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport) report designer is fanstastic too.

Answer (score 3):

[Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/) has a [community edition](http://community.pentaho.com/) that is open source and quite powerful. It also integrates with eclipse, the designer is an RCP application.

Answer (score 2):

[Jasper Reports](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

[BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) (Business Intelligence and Reporting Tools).

Integrates nicely with Eclipse if you happen to use that (already).

Answer (score 2):

It is about how much your company (or client) is willing to pay for.

Someone mentioned YellowFin (YF) which is **NOT** open source. I will give a brief summary about it.

I have been using YF for over a year.

YF is great accessing transactional databases or for dedicated Data Warehouse DB's.

Perfect when you have several reports and need to put a few of them in a dashboard for the end user.

Web based tool, easy to build graphs and export them.

YF license price is arbitrary, according to the customer. There is no specific price. YF is based in Melbourne-Australia.

I am using YF now in a Data Warehouse project and the DW database has around 490GB.

**I am talking about YF because it is something that really works!**

But to answer your question about open source, This one has similar features to YF:

[www.openi.org](http://www.openi.org)

Take a look at the online demo:

http://demo.openi.org/openi/
user and password: openi2

cheers

Leo

Comment: hi, @Leonardo right now my firm is going to use YellowFin 6  .So I have to Handle that one  also I am totally new to that one. Please give me any use full video links or site .

Answer (score 1):

You need to say a little more about your requirements.  Jasper and Docmosis sit at the integration end of your Java system but sounds like you might be after things like Yellowfin and G2.